# Rails not routing edit method using /edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code to attempt to link the customer's name to the edit method.

```
<%= link_to "#{customer.name}", customer, method: :edit %>
```

But when I click on the name it opens up `/customer/1` instead of `/customer/1/edit`

If I manually enter `/customer/1/edit` it opens the page correctly.  The worst part is that it used to do it correctly and then stopped.

How do I get my edit method to use the /edit again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link will be like this..

```
<%= link_to "#{customer.name}", edit_customer_path(customer) %>
```

if you want to mention method in link_to, you can do it as,

```
<%= link_to "#{customer.name}", :controller => 'customers', :action => 'edit' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that first code worked great but when I tried the second one it caused some routing errors...I'm happy to just use the first method but any idea why the second option was failing?

Comment: A URL Generation error:

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers"}

Comment: try with `:controller=>"customer"`

Comment: Same error as well as with :controller=>"customers_controller". As I said, the first solution worked great so I'm happy to stay with it.